# Trouble with tikz and def

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to combine two different suggestions people made about [an earlier question I asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186279/how-to-refine-this-tikz-diagram/186323#186323). I'm getting a bunch of errors, but I'm not sure what the problem is. The code is:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\mycurve#1{(0,0) to[out=70, in=180] (5,1.8)#1}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-0.1,-0.1) rectangle (5,3);                                   
\draw[help lines,->] (0,0) -- (4.2,0);                               
\draw[help lines,->] (0,0) -- (0,3);   % draw axis lines             
\draw[gray,dashed] (0,2) -- (4.2,2);   % draw asymptote              
\draw[domain=0.5:4.6,very thick,red,->,samples=400] \mycurve;% draw plot

\foreach \x  in {0.25,0.5,...,4}                                                
 {
    \draw[help lines,->] (\x,0) -- ($(\x,\mycurve)-(0,0.6pt)$);
  }

\end{tikzpicture}                                                          
\end{document}
```

I think the problem is at the end, where I try to make the vertical lines relative to the curve; it works if the curve is defined as a hyperbola, as in `\def\mycurve#1{{1/(-(\x+#1))+2}}`, but if I define an arbitrary curve it doesn't. Can I not do that, or did I make a code mistake somewhere?

Comment: You have defined `\mycurve` with an argument, but don't supply one, so `#1` becomes the closing parenthesis `)`, messing everything up.

Comment: \mycurve takes an argument but you use it without one like in `\mycurve)`...here TeX will think `)` is your argument and TikZ will not find the closing parens

Comment: @egreg you bit me to it =) `\mycurve;` is problematic too

Comment: Moreover `$(\x,(0,0) to[out=70, in=180] (5,1.8))-(0,0.6pt)$)` is not legal.

Comment: Related to your last paragraph: apparently, `\mycurve` does not define a "curve", but rather a numerical function of `\x` and an arbitrary argument. This numerical function can be understood by `\draw` for a plot, and in a coordinate definition (if there is a `\x` in the context). But indeed you cannot replace it with an "arbitrary curve" which will not make sense in either of these contexts.

Comment: So, to make sure I've got all this: it sounds like I can either define the curve as `(0,0) to[out=70, in=180] (5,1.8)` or define the vertical arrows in relation to the curve, but I can't do both. Is that right?

Comment: PS @egreg where's the illegality in that line you quoted?

Comment: @crmdgn I tried it and it produces tons of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TikZ checks the to-do list on the path by reading the characters in the stream, it is almost always problematic to have a macro sitting by itself. Here, you have intertwined a few problems;

When you define `\mycurve#1{}` you define a macro which will keep looking for an argument until it hits something that calms TeX down. In pacman notation

```
\mycurveᗧ••••••••ᗣ{other definition stuff}
```

it will keep eating until hits one of those ghost thingies. If the stuff is not grouped such as `\mycurve{lots of things that will replace #1}` then it will get stuck in the first `)`. I'm sure there is a duplicate somewhere to explain it better so I'm skipping that. As an example, you are delaying the `;` with your definition;

```
\mycurve;
```

since `#1` is replaced by `;` which is the same thing if you define your macro with

```
\def\mycurve{same definition without #1}
```

However, then you use

```
\mycurve)
```

then it delays the parenthesis and you are putting a `to` path inside a coordinate declaration. You can simply try

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,to (3,5));
```

That's not allowed and also I don't even know what it might mean. But!

When you define it as

```
\def\mycurve#1{{1/(-(\x+#1))+2}}
```

then TikZ is smart enough to understand that it might be a calculation going on there which would lead to a number and it would use it for the y entry of that coordinate. However you still supply a parenthesis to `\mycurve`, so it becomes

```
{1/(-(\x+)))+2}
```

and it shouldn't work. So I don't think that's what you have used previously.